# Is there anything missing in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

The Bolded part of this sentence is confusing and I suppose it is a mistake:

> Governments have the right – and the duty - especially in a crisis, to inform their nationals of the difficult circumstances, or even the dangers they may encounter during their travels abroad; **it is their responsibility however to issue such information without prejudicing in an unjustified or exaggerated manner the tourism industry of the host countries and the interests of their own operators**; the contents of travel advisories should therefore be discussed beforehand with the authorities of the host countries and the professionals concerned; recommendations formulated should be strictly proportionate to the gravity of the situations encountered and confined to the geographical areas where the insecurity has arisen; such advisories should be qualified or cancelled as soon as a return to normality permits; [Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-6)

My problem is with the part * the tourism industry of the host countries and the interests of their own operator*. It is a complete Noun Phrase which seems to lack something preceding it. I feel the writer has missed it. What do you think?

Comment: Looks fine to me - if a little tortuous. Break it down to 'without prejudicing… the other country's tourism industry… or their own country's operators'. Though how they are going to say 'don't go to x because everybody has ebola' could possibly be done without a bit of a hit to the tourist trade ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Commas and dashes, or parentheses.

> ... it is their responsibility, however, to issue such information without prejudicing--in an unjustified or exaggerated manner--the tourism industry of the host countries and the interests of their own operators

or

> ... it is their responsibility, however, to issue such information without prejudicing (in an unjustified or exaggerated manner) the tourism industry of the host countries and the interests of their own operators

The verb *prejudicing* is what "precedes" the phrase "the tourism industry of the host countries and ..." - this phrase is the "object" of *prejudicing* (it answers what is being prejudiced).

The phrase "in an unjustified or exaggerated manner" is a modifier of *prejudicing* (it qualifies the manner of prejudicing).

Comment: Wow! great! What does prejudice mean here? *prejudicing  the tourism industry of the host countries and (prejudicing) the interests of their own operators"* Does it mean *have a bad effect on"*? Does it say *without imposing a harmful influence on both the destination tourism and the operators business*?

Comment: That's basically what it means.  *Prejudice* means more exactly "to allow an unfounded assumption to come to the surface, or to consider such assumptions in making decisions or judgements" - typically an assumption that could cause damage to reputation, etc.